# Rake task during application initialization rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I want to execute a rake task when the server of my application starts.

In config/application.rb i put the following:

```
if !Rails.env.production?
  Rake::Task[ "init:db_records" ].invoke
end
```

The rake task is well defined, and runs without a problem if i invode it from terminal

```
rake init:db_records
```

But when placed in config/application.rb (or even in any initializers/*) i got the following error.

Don't know how to build task 'init:db_records'

What is the way to execute a rake task when the server starts ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who encounter the same problem in the future.

I achieved this by creating a new file in the `initializers` directory, where i put the code of the rake task.

The advantage of this at this point, is that the application is already loaded, so you have access to ActiveRecord functions...

Putting the code directly in config/application.rb didn't work, since my models were not loaded yet.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

Rails already has a mechanism for setting up a development database -- `rake db:seed`. It does not run automatically when you start the app, but it does run as part of `rake db:setup`.

Unless you have a good reason, it's usually best to stick the conventions that Rails provides.

Answer (score 0):

Your Rake tasks are (likely) defined in a `Rakefile`. The `initializer` has no idea that file even exists, so it doesn't know about the tasks within.

The easiest way to circumvent this is by doing something like this:

```
Dir.chdir(Rails.root) do
  `rake init:db_records`
end
```

That is, change the working directory to the root rails directory, then running the command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i "puts the Dir.pwd", i see that i am already in the root directory. Moreover it didn't work, receiving the same error..

Comment: Are you invoking it with the `Rake::Task["name"].invoke` method, or the shell method?

Comment: I invoke it using Rake::Task["name"].invoke method

Comment: I could solve my problem, you can check the details in my answer